# Not able to get first 4 characters of the file name using forfiles in batch command

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd, substring

I'm trying to look for a particular file starting with C2319* from H:\temp folder and delete rest of the files greater than 7 days old

```
forfiles /P "H:\Temp\" /M *d6a0f2b4728a /D -7 /C "md /C for %I in (@path) do @if [%~nI]:~0,4==[c2319] del @file /F /A:S"
```

when executing the above command I'm getting error

```
4==[c2319] was unexpected at this time.
```

Could someone please let me know if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. your command line had a typo: `md` should be `cmd`
2. backslash before quote in `"H:\Temp\"` escapes the quote and should be removed
3. string extraction `:~0,4` (should be `5`, actually) only works for normal variables as it requires both opening and closing `%` or `!`, but since you'll have to assign the loop variable to a variable with delayed expansion (which works only inside batch files) it won't work in `forfiles` /c command.

Here's a faster solution using `robocopy` in list-mode:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set folder=H:\Temp

:: recursively list all *d6a0f2b4728a older than 7 days
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('robocopy /s /njh /njs /ns /nc /ndl /is /l /fp /minage:7 "%folder%" "%folder%" *d6a0f2b4728a') do (

    :: trim spaces
    set file=%%a&set file=!file:%folder%=*!
    for /f "delims=* tokens=2" %%b in ("!file!") do (set file=%folder%%%b&set filename=%%~nb)

    :: delete if not c2319*
    if /i not "!filename:~0,5!"=="c2319" del /F /A:S "!file!"
)
pause
```

Comment: sir please see above comment @wOxxOm

Comment: Hello Sir, I tried the above command as forfiles /P "H:\Temp" /M *d6a0f2b4728a /D -7 /C "cmd /C setlocal enableDelayedExpansion & for %I in (@path) do (set filename=%~nI & if [!filename:~0,4!]==[c2319] del @file /F /A:S)" and I'm still getting the same error as: 4!] was unexpected at this time. –

Comment: thank you sir that worked fine. sorry to keep adding, but is there a way to keep the files starting with name c2319 and delete the rest of the files in the folder. @wOxxOm

Comment: Ah, the objective is something different from what I believed it to be. See the updated code.

Comment: thank you sir, I just tried the code and it is still trying to delete the file with name starting with c2319*, the name of the file is c2319c42033a5ca7f44e731bfd3fa2b5_eb56bdb9-93c5-418a-92ce-d6a0f2b4728a and when I executed the code it deleted this file along with other files older than 7 days. :( @wOxxOm

Comment: Fixed now. That was because I haven't tested it fully.